# scala variable arguments :_*

Tags: scala, scala-collections

could someone bring more shed on following piece of scala code which is not fully clear to me? I have following function defined

```
  def ids(ids: String*) = {
    _builder.ids(ids: _*)
    this
  }
```

Then I am trying to pass variable argument list to this function as follows:

```
def searchIds(kind: KindOfThing, adIds:String*) = {
...
ids(adIds)
}
```

Firstly, `ids(adIds)` piece doesn't work which is a bit odd at first as error message says: Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Seq[String]. This means that variable arguments lists are not typed as collections or sequences.

In order to fix this use the trick `ids(adIds: _*)`.

I am not 100% sure how :_* works, could someone put some shed on it?
If I remember correctly : means that operation is applied to right argument instead to left, _ means "apply" to passed element, ...
I checked String and Sequence scaladoc but wasn't able to find :_* method.

Could someone explain this?

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at your method definitions:

```
def ids(ids: String*)
```

Here you're saying that this method takes a variable number of strings, eg:

```
def ids(id1: String, id2: String, id3: String, ...)
```

Then the second method:

```
def searchIds(kind: KindOfThing, adIds:String*)
```

This also takes a variable number of string, which are packaged into a `Seq[String]`, so `adIds` is actually a `Seq`, but your first method `ids` doesn't take a `Seq`, it takes `N` strings, that's why `ids(adIds: _*)` works.

`: _*` this is called the [splat operator](http://alvinalexander.com/bookmarks/scala/scala%E2%80%99s-missing-splat-operator), what that's doing is *splatting* the `Seq` into `N` strings.

Comment: Updated link: https://alvinalexander.com/bookmarks/scala/scalas-missing-splat-operator